# Invalid identifier error when pivot in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to pivot sales (ie quantity*price) from order_tbl, but getting

> "ORA-00904: "Sales" invalid identifiers".

can anyone please help what wrong is wrong with the below sql?

```
SELECT order_pay, product_id, (quantity * price) as sales
          FROM order_tbl
       PIVOT (SUM (sales) FOR order_pay IN ('01-MAY-2015', '02-MAY-2015'))
```

Script to create table and insert data is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_TBL
(
  ORDER_PAY   DATE,
  ORDER_ID    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  PRODUCT_ID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  QUANTITY    NUMBER(5),
  PRICE       NUMBER(5)
)
```

```
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD1', 'PROD1', 5, 5);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD2', 'PROD2', 2, 10);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD3', 'PROD3', 10, 25);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD4', 'PROD1', 20, 5);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD5', 'PROD3', 5, 25);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD7', 'PROD1', 2, 5);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD8', 'PROD5', 1, 50);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD9', 'PROD6', 2, 50);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD10', 'PROD2', 4, 10);
Insert into ORDER_TBL
   (ORDER_PAY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('5/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'ORD6', 'PROD4', 6, 20);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: `PIVOT (SUM (quantity * price) FOR....` instead of `PIVOT (SUM (sales) FOR....`

Comment: The `pivot` operation is performed **before** the `select` step, how do you expect the execution engine to know what `sales` means? As Igor said in the comment above, change the aggregate in `pivot` to `sum(quantity * price)`. But also note that then you won't have a column `sales` in the output; you will have columns for the two dates in the `in` clause of `pivot`. It would help if you would show your exact expected output, in addition to what you have already shared with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases cannot be used in the same level of query, so `sales` isn't recognised as an identifier in the pivot clause. it also won't recognise `price` or `quantity` with your current query as those aren't in the projection being pivoted, because the calculates `sales` is there instead - which seems a bit contradictory.

As mentioned in comments, you could change the query to do the aggregation directly in the pivot clause (so you don't calculate `sales` as a separate values, and get the two base columns in the initial select list), but that doesn't work either, unless you use an inline view:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT order_pay, product_id, quantity, price
  FROM order_tbl
)
PIVOT (SUM (quantity * price) FOR order_pay IN ('01-MAY-2015', '02-MAY-2015'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e7b96b0320ee0bd1f14d44e2a8f0b1e).

If you particularly want to be able to reference `sales` in the pivot clause then you do that `sales` calculation in an inline view instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT order_pay, product_id, (quantity * price) as sales
  FROM order_tbl
)
PIVOT (SUM (sales) FOR order_pay IN ('01-MAY-2015', '02-MAY-2015'))
```

But '01-MAY-2015' is a string, not a date, so you are relying on implicit  conversion and NLS settings; it would be better to use date literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT order_pay, product_id, (quantity * price) as sales
  FROM order_tbl
)
PIVOT (SUM (sales) FOR order_pay IN (DATE '2015-05-01', DATE '2015-05-02'))
```

And of course you can give the pivoted columns more friendly aliases within the pivot clause too, and order the results, to get something like:

| PRODUCT_ID | May01 | May02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROD1 | 125 | 10 |
| PROD2 | 20 | 40 |
| PROD3 | 250 | 125 |
| PROD4 | *null* | 120 |
| PROD5 | *null* | 50 |
| PROD6 | *null* | 100 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5379b94742cc020fc182ca48c0aedee8)

Comment: What do you mean by "won't recognize `quantity` and `price`"? If you select `quantity` and `price` from the base table into the inline view (instead of performing the multiplication there), they **will** be recognized in `pivot`. If you do need an inline view (as perhaps you do, to ignore the `order_id` column in pivoting - although we don't really know what the desired output is!), then performing the multiplication in the inline view makes sense, but it's a choice, not a requirement.

Comment: Yes, but the OP *is* performing the multiplication there at the moment - `(quantity * price) as sales`. Getting the separate columns is fine too of course. But then you also don't just "change the aggregate in pivot"

Comment: If with the last quoted fragment you are referencing my comment to the OP, please read also what I wrote immediately after that - don't take quotes out of context.

Comment: If you select quantity and price in the inline view, and sum over their product in pivot, there will be **no** quantity called "sales" anywhere - not in the inline view, and certainly not in the output.

Comment: I did read the following sentence, and it doesn't seem to be related. There is no "sales" in the output either way. If you meant that sales isn't calculated in the initial select list then that isn't how it reads to me. (And, actually, [it doesn't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f26ba5c432bb23b0735223e983ff7974) with the calculation inside the sum anyway... I would have expected it to.)

Comment: "that doesn't work either, unless you use an inline view" - that is not true. You can write the query against the base table, you don't need an inline view **for that**. The inline view is only needed because `pivot` assumes aggregation by all columns not referenced in the `pivot` clause. If the OP wants aggregates by product_id AND ORDER_ID, then the query can simply be against the base table. That is why I asked the OP to clarify the desired output. As it is, we are guessing based on his existing (and incorrect) query; who knows what he really needs as the output?